# How to Check whether a element exists in a python dictionary value which is a list?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

How to check whether `'111'` exists in `dic1`?

```
dic1 = {'images':[000,111,222,333,444],'name':['foo','bar','baz']}
```

I tried using List comprehensions but unable to get the boolean answer? I got the error `'int' object is not iterable`.

Comment: Can you please post some sample code?

Comment: @GaneshTata I am working an assignment on MongoDB and python. I got stuck at the problem which is similar to the above-mentioned piece of code.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over `dict.values` and check for existence:

```
dic1 = {'images':[000,111,222,333,444],'name':['foo','bar','baz']}
print(any(111 in b for b in dic1.values()))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ajax1234 :D